# Cannot resolve symbol openDrawer

Tags: android

Im following a tutorial [here] (http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html) and im getting cannot resolve symbol 'openDrawer' and cannot resolve symbol 'closeDrawer'. I just did follow all his steps and copy those codes to my android studio. Any idea why? I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: To get useful response, you have to add your code (see the guidelines of Stackoverflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see below code, openDrawer and closeDrawer are string files.(R.string.openDrawer).

```
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer)
```

So you should add them in your strings file under res--> values--> strings

```
<string name="openDrawer ">Open Drawer </string>
<string name="closeDrawer ">Close Drawer </string>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir Rasika. Your comment really answer my question.